# YAML List Filtering

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

Could someone please assist me on the below:

Either

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tag_info": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {"vm_list": [ "NSY6TFSANSBL01"]},
        ]


OR

ok: [localhost] => {
    "tag_info": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {"vm_list": [ "NSY6TFSANSBL01"]},
            {"vm_list": [ "NSY6TFSANSBL01,NSY6TFSANSBL02"]},
            {"vm_list": [ "NSY6TFSANSBL01,NSY6TFSANSBL02,NSY6TFSANSBL03"]},
        ]

Intersection of N lists works with the code
   - set_fact:
        final_list: "{{ final_list|
                        default(tag_info.results.0.vm_list)|
                        intersect(tag_info.results[item].vm_list) }}"
      loop: "{{ range(1, tag_info.results|length, 1)|list }}"
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I would want the final_list to be {"vm_list": [ "NSY6TFSANSBL01"]} when there is only one vm_list object if not it should intersection of multiple lists.
Could you please let me know how to write that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like so

```
- set_fact:
    final_list: "{{ (tag_info | json_query('results[*].vm_list')|flatten(levels=1)|unique if tag_info.results|length > 1) | default(tag_info.results.0.vm_list) }}"
  loop: "{{ tag_info.results }}"

- debug:
    var: final_list
```

Assumptions:

all vm_list objects as per question is single string in an array.

I am assuming it is not that and it is actually a list of strings as below,

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tag_info": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {"vm_list": [ "NSY6TFSANSBL01"]},
        ]


OR

ok: [localhost] => {
    "tag_info": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {"vm_list": [ "NSY6TFSANSBL01"]},
            {"vm_list": [ "NSY6TFSANSBL01","NSY6TFSANSBL02"]},
            {"vm_list": [ "NSY6TFSANSBL01","NSY6TFSANSBL02","NSY6TFSANSBL03"]},
        ]
```